# Why does Laravel's pluck() method not show special characters correctly?

Tags: eloquent, encoding, laravel-10

I am using Laravel 10. Basically I try to pass the user name to the view. I used to do it in the following way:

```
$user_name = DB::table('users')->select('name')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Then I use it in the view `{{$user_name[0]->name}}`.

It shows special characters as desired. However, as a quicker solution to get the user name I decided to use

```
$user_name = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('name');
```

It shows some special characters `B\u00fcy\u00fck` instead of `Büyük`, for example, when I use it `{{$user_name}}` in my view.

Is there any missing part in my code?

Comment: $user = Users::query()->find($id); $user_name = $user?->name. Btw model name should be User, not Users.

Comment: @Maksim Yes, you are right. It was just a typo. This is not the actual code. I have written an example code line. Actually, it was because of missing first() statement in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_name = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('name');
```

is not enough. I have noticed that I should have add the `first()` method at the end of the chain.

```
$user_name = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('name')->first();
```

It is all right now.